# Firebase & swift use .indexOn to sort data snapshot

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a Firebase/swift newbie and I'm trying to use .indexOn to sort a set of nodes on the server. I've searched SO and the docs to get the rules written but I'm struggling with the correct format for the swift code to use the index.

My assumption is that when I use an .indexOn rule the returned snapshot uses that index to order the result. By using .queryOrderedByChild("title") in swift I negate the server-side performance benefits of creating the index. Please correct me if this assumption is incorrect.

Here's a simplified snippet of my Firebase DB structure:

```
{
  "users": {
    "GkdjgdBJh1TxuAzIPezLWRouG9f2": {
      "messages": {
        "-KM0crettRl-RLQQdmMQ": {
          "body": "Anyone want a bit of body string?",
          "title": "5 Another title string",
        },
        "-KM0dhkChY6ZQ2QzuPlC": {
          "body": "This is a short body string",
          "title": "1 A lovely title string",
        },
        "-FQ0dhkChY6ZQ2Qzu3RQv": {
          "body": "Short and sweet body string",
          "title": "3 I should be in the middle",
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my rule JSON:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
        "users": {
              "$userid": {
                    "messages": {
                          ".indexOn": ["title"]
                    }
              }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my swift code:

```
if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
    // user is logged in

    // *** I think this is the line with the issue ***
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(user.uid).child("messages").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
    messageArray = []

        if let dictionaryOfMessages = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            for messageKey in dictionaryOfMessages.keys {
                messageArray.append(Message(json: JSON(dictionaryOfMessages[messageKey]!)))
                // set the messageId
                messageArray[messageArray.count - 1].messageId = messageKey
            }
        }
        // return the data to the VC that called the function
        success(messages: messageArray)
    }) { (error) in
        // Handle the Error
    }
} else {
    // return some generic messages about logging in etc.
}
```

Any suggestions how I can modify my Swift code to use the index (or correct the index if that's wrong) would be great.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on your question. Are you seeing negative performance impact after adding an index? Or are your results showing out of order?

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen - Bear in mind I'm a newbie so I'm a bit confused. My results are currently showing in the order they're stored in Firebase, not sorted by the index. I read in the docs that it was better to do the sorting on the server using .indexOn so decided to do that up front (my data set is likely to get pretty big) so I can't comment on performance at this stage.

Comment: OK, got it. I'll write an answer. For future questions it's probably best to only mention the part that is going wrong. If the elements in the array are not in the order you expected them to be, performance implications of using an index are irrelevant

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - thanks. I understand your point. However, since I'm a confused newbie, I'm not sure if my indexOn is wrong or whether even with the indexOn correctly in place, I should still be using .queryOrderedByChild() somehow to see the results in the expected sort order. I suppose my Q could be: "does having an .indexOn in rules JSON remove the need to use .queryOrderedByChild() when retrieving sorted data?"

Comment: That last one is indeed a very clear question. The answer is "no". Answer below. Jad's is first, but then you'll probably need mine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **queryOrderedByChild** when you're requesting the data and have a key in your rules as you did. here's an example;

**Firebase documentations**

The following example demonstrates how you could retrieve a list of a user's top posts sorted by their star count:

```
// My top posts by number of stars
let myTopPostsQuery = (ref.child("user-posts").child(getUid())).queryOrderedByChild("starCount")
```

This query retrieves the user's posts from the path in the database based on their user ID, ordered by the number of stars each post has received. This technique of using IDs as index keys is called data fan out.

The call to the queryOrderedByChild method specifies the child key to order the results by. In this case, posts are sorted by the value of the "starCount" child in each post. For more information on how other data types are ordered, see How query data is ordered.

Please follow the link for more details;

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data

Comment: Thanks - I think my confusion arises from the fact that I read in the docs that adding an index to the rules is a good idea. I therefore assumed that an index was *instead* of using .queryOrderedByChild(). As @FrankVanPuffelen has confirmed your answer is correct, I'll follow your advice and move on. Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

First off, you'll need to follow Jad's answer and specify the order in which you want to receive the child nodes. A single list can have many indexes and you'll need to specify what order you want for this specific query.

After specifying an order, the Firebase Database returns a snapshot that contains the nodes matching your query and information about the order in which those nodes appear in the results.

But a dictionary does not have any information about the order of the children. So when your code converts the snapshot into a dictionary, all information about the order is lost:

```
if let dictionaryOfMessages = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
```

For this reason it's best to use the snapshot's built-in method for iterating over the child nodes:

```
for child in snapshot.children {
  let key = child.key as String
  print(key)
  messageArray.append(Message(json: JSON(child.value)))  // JSON handling via SwiftyJSON
  // set the messageId
  messageArray[messageArray.count - 1].messageId = key
}
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming Jad's answer and for the tip about dictionaries. I'm still not sure where the client-side performance benefits of adding the index come from if the client has to order the results after they arrive but I'll move on :-)

Comment: The client doesn't order them, it just returns them in the correct order. A dictionary is unordered, so by converting to a dictionary you are throwing all ordering away.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen based on the code of the OP, if I try to read the database using the Swift library ( not using REST API), do I still have to modify the RULES in Firebase Real Time Database so that the performance of queering improves?