# iOS - OR query in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get all threads where status is `member` or `owner`

I know how to get for either one

```
reference.queryOrdered(byChild: "status").queryEqual(toValue: "owner")
```

Can anyone guide me how to make OR query call?

Comment: firestore is different from firebase database

Comment: @J.Doe From article which you shared  "However, after using it for some time in my own projects, there seems to be something that’s obviously missing — the ability to query with a logical OR."

Comment: My point is that this question has been asked so many times... https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+or

Answer (score 2):

You can't do OR style queries in Firebase.

You can work around this by adding an additional field that is set whenever `status` is `member` or `owner`, and then querying on that field instead.

Comment: Thanks. Since status have only owner or member or nil value. I am able to get my solution using reference.queryOrdered(byChild: "status").queryStarting(atValue: "member").queryEnding(atValue: "owner")

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for `OR` or other multi-clause queries, so you'll have to find another approach.

The simplest mapping would be to have a separate observer for each status and then merge the results client side. Contrary to what many developers think, this scales quite well since [Firebase pipelines the queries/responses over a single connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786).

Alternatively, you might be able to do a range query `queryStarting(atValue: "member").queryEnding(atValue: "status")` of there are no values in between.

Also see:

- [firebase equivalent to sql where in ()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29560088)
- [Advanced Firebase Query with filter in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296815/advanced-firebase-query-with-filter-in-swift/38412587#38412587)
- [Firebase query for multiple where condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47436671/firebase-query-for-multiple-where-condition/47437451#47437451) (showing an example of a range query to match multiple values)
- [OR queries in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034092/or-queries-in-firebase/28036032#28036032) (on an `OR` across multiple properties)
- [Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase/26701282#26701282) (on an `AND` across properties)