# firebase query how can i retrieve two specific values from child

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

i use recyclerview to retrieve a chat messages and i am wondering if there is method to retrieve two different values i mean something like this :

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<enchat> options = 
    new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<enchat>()
        .setQuery(
            mChatDatabase.orderByChild("state").equalTo("sent")
            && mChatDatabase.orderByChild("state").equalTo("received"),
         enchat.class)
        .build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to pass two values into a condition. Firebase Realtime Database doesn't support this type of OR condition.

Also see:

- [Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase/26701282#26701282)
- [iOS - OR query in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52758235/ios-or-query-in-firebase)

The common workarounds are:

- Perform two queries and merge the results in your application code. But you won't be able to use the adapters from FirebaseUI as is in that case.
- Perform a range query, but this only works if there are no `state` values between `received` and `sent`. If that is the case, the query could be:

  ```
  mChatDatabase.orderByChild("state").startAt("received").endAt("sent")
  ```
- Add an additional property that is true when the `state` is either `received` or `sent` and filter on that:

  ```
  mChatDatabase.orderByChild("stateIsReceivedOrSent").equalTo(true)
  ```