# React firebase getting data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase realtime db. I want to get data from firebase with react-firebase-hooks/database library.

I want to get users with certain ids. I know how can i get one user:

`const user = useObjectVal(ref(myDB, "users/123")) // where id = 123`

but what if i need users with id = 123 and id = 456? How can i get data for only two documents from firebase?

I just want something like this:

`const user = useObjectVal(ref(myDB, "users/123&456")) // where id = 123`

Comment: according to the docs https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/tree/master/database#full-example
you have just 2 options: fetch a single user or the list.

Maybe you can simply use 2 variables with userA and userB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to perform an OR with multiple values in the Firebase Realtime Database API. You'll have to perform a separate query for each value and merge the results in your application code.

Also see my answer here:
[iOS - OR query in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52758235/ios-or-query-in-firebase/52762730#52762730)