# Firestore order and limit data returns missing results

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I want to do a few things when I fetch for user records in Firestore:

- filter users within an age range
- filter users based on gender, location
- get the last 6 recently joined users
- get users created before today

```
func observeUsers(){
let location = "Paris"
let gender = "male"
let startAge = 15
let endAge = 30
let today: Double = Date().timeIntervalSince1970

var query = db.collection("users") as Query

query
.whereField("location", isEqualTo: location)
.whereField("age", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: startAge)
.whereField("age", isLessThanOrEqualTo: endAge)
.order(by: "age", descending: true) 
.order(by: "created", descending: true)
.start(at: [today])
.limit(to: 6)
.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let err = error {
                print(err.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            guard let docs = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                return
            }
            docs.forEach({ (doc) in
                print(doc.data())
            })
}
}
```

I have only one composite index enabled `location Ascending gender Ascending age Descending created Descending`

Every user has the same fields: `["gender": male, "created": 1585606054.78943, "firstname": Seven, "location": Paris, "age": 22 ]`

When the query is limited to 12 all users are returned: `Seven, Brian, Aaron, Chuck, Sally, Marty,  Jessie, Trevor, Riley, Boren, Michael, France`

When the query is limited to 6, the following users are returned in this order: 
`Chuck, Sally, Marty, Jessie, Riley, Boren`

**EXPECTED:** `Seven, Brian, Aaron, Chuck, Sally, Marty` the first six users to be returned

Is the problem with back pagination or indexing? Is it because I’m ordering data by two fields? Is the query cursor not unique enough?

Help is very appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using plain javascript to see what happens?

Comment: @Jonathan Do you mean firebase's cloud functions? I haven't explored it much, but changing languages shouldn't affect the query or data returned?

Comment: There could be a bug in the Swift interface.  However, it looks like you changed the Start() function and the limit() function, which will definitely change your results.

Comment: What is `.start(at: [today])` .... [today]? Did you try printing that out to see what that property contains?

Comment: @Jay today is a Double I assigned `let today: Double = Date().timeIntervalSince1970`. Even if I don't include `.start(at: [today])` and only limit results, the data is not correctly returned, dont know why

Comment: Right off the bat, this `let fruits: [String] = [] ` is an empty array so you can't query by that. I assume it's actually populated but as shown will cause the code to crash.

Comment: This comment is after the code was updated: The new code is going to be limiting - what if you want users whose favorite fruit is "ea", "id" or they don't have one. The proposed query won't support. See my updated answer.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan how would changing the Start() and limit() function change my results? I updated and distilled my question

Answer (score 1):

In the question, the fruits array is empty and that would actually cause the query to crash. So I updated the code by adding some fruits to that array with one from each user collection so they would match the query.

I populated a COLLECTION_USERS collection in Firestore with your exact data - with one exception in that the document id's were uid_0, uid_1, uid_2 but the fields are an exact match.

I then ran my updated code it it returns all three users.

Here's the updated code which is identical except for those couple of changes. (I also added in the today var as mentioned in the comments)

```
func querySomeData() {
    var fruits: [String] = []
    let location = "New York"
    let gender = "male"
    let startAge = 20
    let endAge = 30
    let today: Double = Date().timeIntervalSince1970

    fruits.append(contentsOf: ["ea", "et", "id"])

    let collectionUsers = self.db.collection("COLLECTION_USERS")
    collectionUsers
        .whereField("favoriteFruits", arrayContainsAny: fruits)
        .whereField("location", isEqualTo: location)
        .whereField("gender", isEqualTo: gender)
        .whereField("age", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: startAge)
        .whereField("age", isLessThanOrEqualTo: endAge)
        .order(by: "age", descending: true) // or ascending
        .order(by: "created", descending: true)
        .start(at: [today])
        .limit(to: 6)
        .getDocuments() { querySnapshot, error in

            if let err = error {
                print(err.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            guard let docs = querySnapshot?.documents else { return }

            for doc in docs {
                print(doc.documentID)
            }

    }
}
```

and the output

```
uid_0
uid_2
uid_1
```

So barring those couple of differences (adding fruits to the array and the documentID) the code in the question works.

**EDIT:**

The OP also wants to return users who don't have a favorite fruit, so the array in Firestore would be empty. You can't query for an empty array as a non-empty array is required for 'arrayContainsAny' filters. So the simple solution is to add a placeholder (very common in NoSQL databases) indicating the user doesn't have a favorite fruit. So the array in Firestore would look like this:

```
favoriteFruits
   0: "none"
```

and the query would include this

```
fruits.append(contentsOf: ["ea", "et", "id", "none"])
```

which would return all users who have those favorite fruits, or no favorite fruits.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210626/discussion-on-answer-by-jay-firestore-order-and-limit-data-returns-missing-resul).